# why doesn't a client using UDP connect to an HTTP server correctly?

Tags: http, networking, udp

I am not quite sure I understand why this doesn't work. Is this possible? What are the pitfalls of using this if we decide it is possible?

Comment: I fail to see the sense behind such attempt. UDP does not offer any protection against package loss. What should such a client do with pages or object received only partially?

Comment: The answer to the question in your *title* is that HTTP works over TCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually efforts pursuing such an approach. It ultimately led to the development of [coap](/questions/tagged/coap). But plain HTTP cannot work on UDP, as all packets being sent out are essentially "fire and forget," lacking any guarantee for them to arrive their designated target. Also, order of packets can be entirely different on the receiving side. I believe there were some efforts to get HTTP running via [sctp](/questions/tagged/sctp), though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seriously going down this route, you may want to look at QUIC: https://www.chromium.org/quic